# Time complexity of similar-looking functions

Tags: time-complexity, c++

What is the time complexity of the following functions, and why?

````
int f(int n)
{
    if (n <= 1) return n;               
    return 2*f(n-1);
}

int g(int n)
{
    if (n <= 1) return n;               
    return g(n-1) + g(n-1);
}
```
````

Comment: You might be wondering whether they have the same time complexity or not. Try writing the recurrence relation for the run times for both of them.

Comment: Rather than suggesting a code layout fix, I ask you to present both implementations as [*pseudocode*](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/33884).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a system behind the magic of algorithm analysis?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis)

Comment: I think you have all missed the point of this question. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is actually subtler than it looks.

Let us first consider a naive compiler. This naive compiler will implement the recursive case of $g$ by actually running $g(n-1)$ twice. The recurrences for the running time will be
\begin{align*}
T_f(n) &= T_f(n-1) + O(1) & T_f(1) &= O(1), \\
T_g(n) &= 2T_g(n-1) + O(1) & T_g(1) &= O(1),
\end{align*}
whose solutions are $T_f(n) = O(n)$ and $T_g(n) = O(2^n)$.

Usually we allow the compiler to perform some optimizations. It could potentially optimize the calculation of $g(n-1) + g(n-1)$ by first computing $x = g(n-1)$, and then calculating $x + x$ or $2x$ (or potentially $x \ll 1$). However, this should be done with care, since it could have modified the semantics of the program. Suppose for example that we modify the code by adding *side-effects*:

```
int fx(int n)
{
    printf("x");
    if (n <= 1) return n;               
    return 2*fx(n-1);
}

int gx(int n)
{
    printf("x");
    if (n <= 1) return n;               
    return gx(n-1) + gx(n-1);
}
```

In this case $fx(2)$ results in printing $xx$ while $gx(2)$ results in printing $xxx$. Therefore an optimizer cannot convert $gx$ into $fx$, though it could convert $g$ to $f$. A smart optimizer will be able to detect, using static analysis, that there are no side effects in $g$, and so convert $g$ to $f$.

I tried it out with clang version 12.0.0. Without any optimizations (`-O0`), the function $g$ has two recursive calls. With optimizations (`-O1` and higher), the code of $g$ becomes identical to the code of $f$. The code of $gx$ is of course unaffected.